# How to know that Event.respondWith has finished(callback for Event.respondWith()

Tags: service-worker, fetch-api

Currently i have a logic in ServiceWorker where i need to check within Service Worker if a particular event.respondWith() has finished or not , only after that i need to delete the cache.Is there any way to know that.I checked that event.respondWith() does not have a then() or callback .

Comment: Could you clarify the question?

Comment: Basically i want to know if i can have a callback function for event.respondWith(), how to know from serviceworker that a request is completed?

Answer (score 2):

If your cache cleanup is independent of the `Response` that's being used to fulfill the Promise passed to `event.respondWith()`, then you can (probably) just kick it off asynchronously inside the `fetch` event handler without worrying about whether `event.respondWith()` has completed. This would be the case if you, for instance, want to clean up a cache whenever it's grown past *N* entries in size.

If your cache cleanup is specific to the `Response` that's being used to fulfill the Promise, then you're going to want to insert the logic into the Promise chain, making sure that you end the chain by fulfilling with the valid `Response`. I'm assuming that you have control over the `fetch` event handler and can do that. Here's an general (untested) approach:

```
self.addEventListner('fetch', event => {
  const p = promiseThatFulfillsWithResponse(); // Your logic goes here.

  event.respondWith(p.then(response => {
    return caches.open('my-cache-name')
      .then(cache => cache.delete(event.request)) // Or whatever you want to delete.
      .then(() => response); // Return response at the end of the chain!
  });
});
```

You don't want to do too much inside your Promise chain, since everything you do will delay the `Response` being passed to the controlled page.

Comment: You could also do `p.then(_ => { deleteTheCache(); })` after `const p`, and then just `event.respondWith(p)`.